# Any() Operator in LINQ Chaining

Tags: c#, .net, performance, linq, directory

i have a following Query

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any()
```

If Any One .txt files present than above expression returns true. my doubts is does the above recursive enumeration stops on first occurance of .txt or Directory.GetFiles() gives list of All .txt and then Any() function will be applied on the IEnumerable sent by GetAllFiles().

My Intention is to find whether the given path has atleast any one txt file or not

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> my doubts is does the above recursive enumeration stops on first occurance of .txt

No, `Directory.GetFiles` returns`string[]` So it reads all files. Use `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Any();
```

Comment: And does it stop after the first file? It's a good correction but you do not explicitly answer the core question.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I said `A` doesn't do what OP expects and suggested to use `B`. What is unclear?

Comment: The OP asked about `C`: when does Any() stop.

Comment: I'm sure that if you read the documentation of the involved method you'll find the answers. This answer also answers `D`: "why is this getting all 10000 .txt files to see if one exists". `Any` will stop iterating the array of files as soon as one is found on the array of all files using the OP's code.

Comment: Thanks L.B.well explained.